# How do we verify jwt token in graphql server

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am using a query getUsers to fetch the user by passing the token to header

```
let user
getUsers: async (_,__,context) => {
        
            if(context.req && context.req.headers.authorization){
                const token = context.req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1]
                jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET, (err, decodedToken) =>{
                    if(err){
                    throw new AuthenticationError("Unauthenticated")
                     }
                     
                     user = decodedToken

                    console.log(user)
                 })
            }
```

But this is throwing the error `"Unauthentication"`, When I tried to `console.log(decodedToken)`. It was showing `undefined`. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Please provide more information regarding how you do the request itself

Comment: @Noam I have created the login query, and by executing the login query I am getting a jwt token in response. Now I am passing that particular token to the HTTP header, to fetch that particular user using getUser query. But while executing the above code I am getting unauthenticated error as response. When I tried to debug it using console.log, I was able to get the token but wasn't able to get the proper response from jwt.verify.

Comment: Do `console.log(err)` instead to see *why* you are getting that error!

Comment: console.log(err) showing invalid token. But the same token when I am validating from jwt.io tools is giving the desired payload.